# Starting Magento API login

Tags: php, api, magento

When I call the login method, on the Magento API, it creates this error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:152:"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://perfumesbook.com//api/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://perfumesbook.com//api/?wsdl"
";i:1;s:3521:"#0 /var/www/clients/client20/web25/web/app/design/adminhtml/default/go/template/moloni/classes/core.class.phtml(283): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://perfumes...')
```

What i'm doing wrong? :s

```
  $api = new SoapClient("http://perfumesbook.com/api.php?type=soap&wsdl=1");
  $session = $api->login('[USER}', '[PASS]');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your wsdl file is missing or you didn't load that file. Make sure about this..

Comment: yeah..I tried that..it returns nothing..It could be some error either the file is missing..

Comment: Well, i've noticed that if i'm logged in the admin area, and I open the url, it shows up, but if I start a private sesseion, it doesnt :s

Comment: OKAy..It seems like you didn't give proper permission for your user. Make sure you gave the full permission for your user in magento admin ->web services->Roles . create new roles with full access. Then assign that role to your user..

Comment: Tried that, user is full permissions, and still same error :s

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that your WSDL file point to wrong URL, check the last few lines. It says

```
<service name="MagentoService">
<port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding">
<soap:address location="http://perfumesbook.com/index.php/?type=soap"/>
</port>
</service>
```

The WSDL template defined in *app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc/wsdl.xml*, and link it self built in *app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Base.php*

Comment: Then What should I do? S: Can I adapt my script, or I need to change the XML?

Comment: The Address i get in another Magento Instalation, is index.php/api/index/index/

Comment: Doesn't seems like a good idea. I have tried to open your website, and I saw a blank page. Try to figure out what is wrong with index.php, and then try to use this url - http://perfumesbook.com/api/soap/. I think in the latest versions of magento they change 'workflow' for API to use same entry point (index.php) as for all website.

Comment: Humm.. Is there anyway of re-installing just the API part of Magento?

Comment: Yes, but you need to replace URL in the WSDL template or ../Config/Base.php. Don't see other solution to make api.php work.

Comment: Or, replace route name and controller name in Request object in the api.php.

Comment: I've compared two Base.php files, where they set the XML properties, and from both installations its the same, but one works, another doesnt... gonna try to change manually the URL in the XML

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41019/discussion-between-nunong21-and-sergey)

Comment: I think there is a way to make all this stuff working using apache RewriteEngine. Sorry, I don't have magento installation available to try this solution.